# Overriding border bottom in mat select

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have created a [stackblitz example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/qhqdjp?file=src%2Fexample%2Fselect-overview-example.html,src%2Fexample%2Fselect-overview-example.scss,src%2Fstyles.scss). I am tring to hide

[image]

but no matter whatever I try or look to override, I can't hide this underline.

I am trying to override it in styles.scss so that is changed across application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the below CSS to remove the bottom line.

```
body {
  font-family: Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

mat-form-field {
  .mat-mdc-form-field-type-mat-select {
    background-color: #ffff !important;
  }
  .mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  /* CSS to remove line - start */
  .mdc-text-field--filled .mdc-line-ripple::before,
  .mdc-text-field--filled .mdc-line-ripple::after {
    border-bottom: 0px !important;
  }
  /* CSS to remove line - end */
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/qhqdjp-i3grex)